# Parameter Pack Confusion

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, tuples, variadic-templates

I just came across a very strange situation when writing a `C++11` `std::tuple`-like class and trying to compile it with `g++-4.7`. What I basically need is a tuple of wrapped types. I wrote something like this:

```
#include <tuple> 

template <class T> 
struct Wrapper { T x; }; 

template <class... Types> 
using Tuple = std::tuple<Wrapper<Types>...>; 

template <class... Types> 
struct X 
{ 
    using MyTuple = Tuple<Types...>; 
}; 

int main( int argc, char** argv ) 
{ 
    // Tuple<int,int> t;  // (1)
    using Y = X<int,int>;
    Y y;                  // (2)
    return 0; 
}
```

I made the following observations:

1. The code does not compile:
2. If I add `(1)`, it does compile.
3. If I remove `(1)` and `(2)`, it does compile as well.

Error message for 1.:

```
test.cpp: In instantiation of ‘struct X<int, int>’:
test.cpp:22:4:   required from here
test.cpp:10:44: error: wrong number of template arguments (2, should be 1)
test.cpp:4:8: error: provided for ‘template<class T> struct Wrapper’
```

**Question:** In my opinion the code above is correct, but it is the first time that I actually use parameter packs. Are there any reasons that `g++-4.7` does not like my code except for the fact that it is an experimental implementation?

Comment: The code you provided compiles just fine, and from the error it seems that you accidentally wrote `std::tuple<Wrapper<Types...>>` instead of `std::tuple<Wrapper<Types>...>`. Please provide the real code and try it again before posting.

Comment: [Compiles in GCC 4.8.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=2250fa21d618a80511a96c95725346f5-50d9cfc8a1d350e7409e81e87c2653ba)

Comment: This is the real code. I thought that I made the error that you describe, but in fact I did not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most likely a [bug in g++ 4.7](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52380) that is fixed in g++ 4.8. Ideone (which uses g++ 4.7.2, and which I cannot link to without duplicating your code example, argh) gives the error you mention, whereas [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=2250fa21d618a80511a96c95725346f5-50d9cfc8a1d350e7409e81e87c2653ba) (using g++ 4.8) compiles without error.

Comment: It's not Stacked-Crooked. It's Coliru. Though it is Stack-Croocked's.

Comment: it's called Stacked-Crooked on http://isocpp.org/get-started, not that it matters

Comment: I can confirm that GCC 4.7.2 gives the error, while GCC 4.8 and 4.9 snapshot do not. But the specific bug you link to says "fixed for 4.7.1"..?

Comment: @rhalbersma: It didn't have a name when it was added there, so they likely just took the address - but the creator of it ([StackedCrooked](http://stackoverflow.com/users/75889/stackedcrooked)) named it "Coliru", and that's also what's displayed at the top when in edit mode. :)

Comment: @jogojapan the bug I linked had the same error message and samme language feature, but occurred in a different context than this question. Just speculating, but it could have the same underlying defect, that was partially fixed in 4.7.1 and more fully in 4.8. I can't locate the same bug for 4.7.2, though.

Comment: @Xeo fixed. BTW what happened to my beloved LiveWorkSpace, which has been under maintaince for a month now?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the bug has been fixed between 4.7.2 and 4.7.3.